# How can I get rid of [webpack-dev-server] Server started: Hot Module Replacement enabled？

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, error-handling, webpack-dev-server

I have an error says in the screenshot below and I don't know what to do.
It says something in index.js on the right.
If anyone know, please guide me through. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: that doesn't look like an error - that looks like information telling you that the webpack-dev-server HMR is running - not everything logged to the console is an error - some things are informational

Comment: Got it. I was wondering what it was too. Thanks, @JaromandaX!